# Date "at which" - Date "for when" - Date "on which"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, dates

Which of these three phrases is better/correct?

- Date **at which** it will be enabled
- Date **for when** it will be enabled
- Date **on which** it will be enabled

This is for instructions to a user to enter a date.

Comment: When you [searched for these](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Date+at+which%2C+date+for+which%2C+date+on+which&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CDate%20at%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdate%20for%20which%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdate%20on%20which%3B%2Cc0), which did you find to be more common?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Date on which it will be enabled" is best.

You can see why in the following dialogue. Try changing "on" to different prepositions in your head - you will see that they won't work.

"On which date will it be enabled?"

"On Monday."

"Will I be able to view it on that date?"

"The date on which you can view it is the same date on which it will be enabled."